# What are the real names of the members of Organisation XIII?

Tags: kingdom-hearts

In Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days we see how Roxas is actually an anagram of Sora with an X in it and Axel's original names is Lea, as mentioned by Saix. I also remember reading somewhere that Xemnas's name is anagram of Ansam.

So I am wondering, what are the original names for all the Organisation XIII members?

Comment: Annoying that an edit needs to be 6 letters. The name of the game is 358/2 not 356/2.

Comment: @Philbo thanks for pointing that out, i made that edit myself since i don't have that limit (either because of my rep or because i'm the the owner of the post)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I. Xemnas = <s>[Ansem](http://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Ansem,_Seeker_of_Darkness)</s> [Xehanort](http://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Xehanort)
- II. Xigbar = [Braig](http://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Braig) (Bleig, in the NA version of KH2)
- III. Xaldin = [Dilan](http://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Dilan) (Dilin; Ibid)
- IV. Vexen = [Even](http://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Even)
- V. Lexaeus = [Aeleus](http://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Aeleus) (Eleus; Ibid)
- VI. Zexion = [Ienzo](http://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Ienzo)
- VII. Saïx = [Isa](http://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Isa)
- VIII. Axel = [Lea](http://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Lea)
- IX. Demyx = ???
- X. Luxord = ???
- XI. Marluxia = [Lauriam](https://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Lauriam)
- XII. Larxene = [Elrena](https://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Elrena)
- XIII. Roxas = [Sora](http://kingdomhearts.fandom.com/wiki/Sora)

> XIV. Xion = "nobody," Sora's (imperfect) replica with Kairi's memories. 
>  From the Tomoko Tanemaki, one of the scenario writers and writer of the KH novel: Xion's name contains the Japanese words for "tide" (潮, shio), fitting the oceanic naming theme of Kairi, Naminé, and [Aster tataricus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aster_tataricus) (紫苑, shion), which according to [Japanese floriography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanakotoba), means "I won't forget you" or "remembrance."